# Fast gradient-descent implementation in a C++ library?

Tags: c++, optimization, gradient-descent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast gradient-descent implementation in a C++ library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513926/fast-gradient-descent-implementation-in-a-c-library)

I'm looking to run a gradient descent optimization to minimize the cost of an instantiation of variables.  My program is very computationally expensive, so I'm looking for a popular library with a fast implementation of GD. What is the recommended library/reference?

Comment: The GSL (GNU Scientific Library) http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/ isn't bad, I've used it frequently before.  Alternatively, you could call the R optimization routines from C++, but that's more work.

Comment: If you're down to worrying about such costs, you're probably better off searching for a new method, such as Newton's method, conjugate gradients, etc.  What works will depend on your specific problem.